# Android Scanning working Fine with simulator ,not working with real beacon hardware

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon, altbeacon

I created a beacon scanning app in Android. The goal of the app is to identify whether the beacon is scanned or not

The app I have tested with beacon simulator app on android. One of my mobile acting as a beacon transmitter. The app works fine and detects beacon signals transmitted by mobile but when my client tested it with real beacons then the app didn't detect the beacon. The app is working fine with the simulator beacon app but not working with real beacons.

Mobile device model and OS version
Android 8.0 and Android 7.0

Android AltBeacon Library version
2+ in Gradle Dependency

Comment: It sounds silly, but do you have bluetooth enabled on your phone?

Comment: There are various types of BLE beacons: iBeacon, Eddystone, Altbeacon being the ones I'm familiar with. So, your app might e.g. scan for Eddystone beacons and the client might have iBeacons. There are ways to configure the Android Beacon Library to scan for any of these types, but only one at a time, I believe.

Comment: @ Joshua best  yes bluetooth is opened . I tested with eddystone and altbeacon on beacon simulator app . But it is not scanning real device

Comment: Can you detect the beacon with an off the shelf beacon scanner like BeaconScope?  If so, please show a screen shot and your scanning setup code

Comment: The most likely explanation is that your client is testing the app with a beacon that is (a) not working (b) not transmitting a format and/or identifiers that your app is set up to detect.  If you cannot be in the same place as your client, ask the client to use the [BeaconScope](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.davidgyoungtech.beaconscanner&hl=en_US) app to detect the beacon and send you a screenshot.

Comment: @davidgyoung You are right, thanks a lot your point indicated the lap in my app. I asked my client to tell me the name of the manufacturer whose beacon he is using . When he told me I came to know that beacon is based on ibeacon format . It resolved my issue .
I'll recommend each person reading this thread please confirm the beacon manufacturer before testing .

Comment: Glad you found the solution.  I converted my comment to an answer.  If you can accept it and comment there about it being iBeacon it might help others who see this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that your client is testing the app with a beacon that is (a) not working (b) not transmitting a format and/or identifiers that your app is set up to detect. If you cannot be in the same place as your client, ask the client to use the BeaconScope app to detect the beacon and send you a screenshot.